# What happens to ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore when the server is restarted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activesupport

What happens to ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore when the server is restarted? Is the small chunk of memory persisted to disk? If I theoretically ran a Rake task that pre-loaded the cache, would that data be persisted between the Rake task and the start of the production server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore is not persisted at all. It's not even shared between processes, so if you are hosting with Passenger, Unicorn, etc the cache will be completely separate for each backend process.  If you want a cache that can be persisted to disc take a look at [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it's the way to go. Will I manually have to manage the redis process or will the gems take care of that for me?